# Custom route is not hitting in asp.net core mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have sample .net core mvc application, im testing SEO friendly url creating , 
which is posted [Here](https://rehansaeed.com/seo-friendly-urls-asp-net-core/)

I have created all the code as in the post.

My testing controller action is as follows

```
 public IActionResult Index(int id, string titl)
        {
            //string titl = "";
            var viewModel = new FriendlyUrlViewModel() { Id = 1, Name = "Detail home view." };

            string friendlyTitle = FriendlyUrlHelper.GetFriendlyTitle(viewModel.Name);

            // Compare the title with the friendly title.
            if (!string.Equals(friendlyTitle, titl, StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {
                return RedirectToRoutePermanent("post_detail", new { id = viewModel.Id, title = friendlyTitle });
            }

            return View(viewModel);

        }
```

and i have create custom route in `startup.cs`

```
 app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "post_detail",
                    template: "FriendlyUrl/index/{id}/{title}"
                ).MapRoute(
                        name: "default",
                        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            });
```

when i navigate to

```
https://xxxxx:2222/FriendlyUrl/index/2/dfdsfdsfds
```

browser display nothing,
I think issue is with custom routing, but i cant find it,
can someone help on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to add:

```cs
routes.MapRoute(
name: "post_detail",
template: "FriendlyUrl/index/{id}/{title}")
```

That is for the global 'controller/action' map rule.

Instead, to map specified path to action, consider adding an attribute like this:

```cs
 [Route("FriendlyUrl/index/{id}/{title}")]
 public IActionResult Index([FromRoute]int id, [FromRoute]string title)
 {

 }
```

## FAQ

#### How to use route name to redirect?

Simply add a name to your route. Like this:

```cs
 [Route("FriendlyUrl/index/{id}/{title}", Name = "post_detail")]
 public IActionResult Index([FromRoute]int id, [FromRoute]string title)
 {

 }
```

To route to this action from another controller or action, call it with:

```cs
// in action
return RedirectToRoute("post_detail");
// or
return RedirectToRoutePermanent("post_detail");
// I guess you don't have to lose the `Id`:
return RedirectToRoutePermanent("post_detail", new { id = 5 });
```

#### How to allow receiving null to title

Simply add a `?` to the route template. Like this:

```cs
 [Route("FriendlyUrl/index/{id}/{title?}", Name = "post_detail")]
 public IActionResult Index([FromRoute]int id, [FromRoute]string title)
 {

 }
```

Comment: I have tried it. but i have two concerns
1.How do i use RedirectToRoutePermanent
2.Receiving null to title

Comment: @Roshan Please check the answer again.